# Delphi's IdHTTP.get and PHP's file_get_contents show different text for the same URL

Tags: php, xml, delphi, http, file-get-contents

I have this [link](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw?v=2).

I have numerous times successfully downloaded its corresponding data with `IdHTTP.Get(link)` (Delphi 2009).

Here's the partial result that I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007" gd:etag="W/&quot;DEIMRn47eCp7I2A9XRdXF0o.&quot;">
  <id>tag:youtube.com,2008:user:-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw</id>
  <published>2010-04-29T10:54:00.000Z</published>
  <updated>2014-10-31T17:29:47.000Z</updated>
  ...
</entry>
```

In PHP I do:

```
$content = file_get_contents(link);
echo $content;
```

This is the exact result I see on page:

```
tag:youtube.com,2008:user:-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw2010-04-29T10:54:00.000Z2014-10-31T17:29:47.000ZBusinessy stuff: business dot pewdiepie at gmail dot comPewDiePiehttp_gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/PewDiePie-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5YwUC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw117663191659499528404SE-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Ywpewdiepie
```

New to PHP. Please tell where is my mistake.

Comment: "had to destroy the links due to stackoverflow's policies" --> If you indent 4 spaces the lines are seen as code and you can put everything in. I have changed that , you can now [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26681037/edit) the full information in (it looks like there may be some line feeds missing).

Comment: What happens if you put `header('Content-type: text/plain')` in the PHP version? It looks like the XML is being interpreted as HTML by the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the same result in PHP, but you output it as HTML to the browser. The browser ignores all tags that it doesn't know and outputs the text content. Open the source view in the browser and you will see the tags.

### Alternatives:

Output the result with escaped entities:

```
$content = file_get_contents(link);
echo htmlspecialchars($content);
```

Output the result as plain text:

```
$content = file_get_contents(link);
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo $content;
```

Comment: I did as you wrote. Now everything works properly. Thanks a lot.